# How to use docker volume with docker image from dockerhub

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Deploy my project using docker compose. At the moment, my project is being built locally, from local folders with projects. Docker uses Laravel service, VueJS service, NGINX service, Mysql service and Redis service.
I set up a docker compose from an article from digital ocean. The question is as follows. In the article, it was necessary to create volumes (volumes) that linked the files of my application locally with the files of the container, but what should I do if I want to build my project using DockerHub, after all, I will no longer have the files stored locally.

I tried without these volumes in the backend and webserver, but then without any errors during the assembly, I cannot reach the server via the localhost.

Do I just need to push the image right away with the volume? Here is my compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'
  services:
    #VueJS Service
    frontend:
      build: ./frontend
      container_name: frontend
      restart: unless-stopped
      tty: true
      environment:
        SERVICE_NAME: frontend
      working_dir: /var/www/frontend
      ports:
        - "3000:80"
      volumes:
        - ./frontend/:/var/www/frontend
        - ./frontend/node_modules:/var/www/frontend/node_modules
      networks:
        - backend-network

  #PHP Service
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    container_name: backend
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: backend
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/var/www
      - ./backend/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - backend-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/var/www
      - ./backend/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - backend-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "33062:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: qcortex
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: kc3wcfjk5
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./backend/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - backend-network

  #Redis
  redis:
    image: caster977/redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: redis
    networks:
      - backend-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  backend-network:
    driver: bridge

#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Comment: you can build your own images using those images as starting point

Comment: Hi the bind mounts are not used when doing the image build, so if you need include default configs or any other file into your image you would do that in your Dockerfile not your compose file.  Removing your volume entries from your compose file will not affect the images built, it will affect the containers that are created when you do a `docker-compose up -d` or similar.